# Posting apostrophe in option value combobox causing truncation

Tags: php, post, apostrophe

I am having an issue with a posted value from an option value combobox if it contains an apostrophe.  The value is being truncated at the apostrophe. The values come from a database where they sit happily with apostrophes.

I understand why this happening, but I don't know how to work around it.  Any ideas?  Thanks in advance.

```
echo "<tr><td>Location:</td>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $dropdown_location .= "\r\n<option value='{$row['location']}'>{$row['location']}</option>";
}

$dropdown_location .= "\r\n</select>";
echo "<td>" . $dropdown_location . "</td> </tr>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is quiet messy, and you are not clear with your question whether you have problem while posting or while retrieving the data, always use `mysqli_real_escape_string()` to escape quotes, before posting data in the database, and sanitize your data, moreover stop using `mysql_()`, use `mysqli_()` or `PDO` because `mysql_()` are no more maintained by PHP community..

Read the big red box [**here**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php)

Instead use these [mysqli_()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

Comment: The problem is when I retrieve the posted value.  Thank you for you comments, but I am not a professional and am working on this as a hobby.  I am doing the best I can by teaching myself.

Comment: @user1658170 so I suggest you to always sanitize your data before you post it in your database :) secondly use `mysqli_()`, I've given you a link, give it a read :)

Answer (score 1):

you can use php heredoc for mixing up html, strings, php variables etc:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

```
$content .= <<< END
 <tr><td>Location:</td>
END;

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

$dropdown_location .= <<< END
     <option value="$row[location]">$row[location]</option>
END;
}

$content .= <<< END

 <td><select name="location">$dropdown_location</select></td></tr>

END;

echo $content;
```

Please note its advised not to have any free space after in the line containing END and END;

Answer (score 0):

You could try htmlspecialchars?
This should let you do what you want.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php